# Should I protect 'this' from deletion in its own member functions?

Tags: c#

The use case:

```
class TheClient
{
  void funcClient()
  {   
     // Local objet with long process
     ClassLast  objServ1 = new ClassLast();

     // Starting ClassLast long process in separated thread
     Thread thCaller = new Thread( objServ1.FunctionThatLastALot ));
     thCaller.Start();

    // Now Leaving funcClient, the local objServ1 will be deleted (!)
  }
}
```

Question:
Does objServ1 may be deleted as soon as the functionClient ends (And I could apply the solution below) ? Because leaving the function, we have no more reference on this object.
Or is there an internal CSharp mechanism that prevents the deletion as long as its member is running ?

If the object is subject to deletion while running, do you thing this should be a solution ? :

```
class ClassLast 
{
  void FuncThatLastALot()
  {    
     // auto-referencing to prevent deletion
     ClassLast me = this;
     // …
     // Process and keep calm, we have time 
     // … 
  }  
}
```

Comment: `this` won't be garbage collected as long as something has a reference to it. Unless you're mucking about with unmanaged memory, there is no risk of anything you need being garbage collected while you're still using it.

Comment: Also note that assigning something to a local variable makes no difference -- the GC will happily collect objects which are still in scope, provided that no subsequent code actually uses them. If you're working with unmanaged memory you may have to do some workarounds, but this gets complex and typically means using a `SafeHandle`. For normal managed code, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: (Specifically, if `FuncThatLastALot` calls any methods on `ClassLast`, or accesses any fields on it, that `ClassLast` instance will not be garbage collected while `FuncThatLastALot` is still executing, and could still access a field / call a method)

Comment: I think you're coming from a C++ background? This is not C++. Objects are not "deleted" when they go out of scope. They become eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to them.

Comment: The only circumstance where an object may be garbage collected whilst one of its member functions is still running is when the remaining reachable parts of that member function *will not* access the object any further. The GC is good, you don't have to try to help it.

Comment: _"The GC is good, you don't have to try to help it."_ - Most attempts to do so will actually be rather detremental.

Comment: @Canton7 :  So, if FuncThatLastALot doesn't access the class members, for example it reads files and make calculations, the instance may be deleted while running ?...

Comment: @iksess Potentially. And that's fine. If `FuncThatLastsALot` doesn't attempt to access any class members, then there's no harm in those class members being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Version: No. You dont need to add this kind of protection. The object will persist as long as it is needed, even if the creating function has been left. The thread will "keep it alive" to run the function and only let it be deleted AFTER its done with it. If you wanna have a little "proof of Concept"

```
public class Programm 
{
    public class TheClient
    {
        public void FuncCall()
        {
            ClassLast last = new();
            Thread thCaller = new Thread(last.FuncLastLot);
            thCaller.Start();
        }
    }

    public class ClassLast
    {
        public void FuncLastLot()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Function End");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TheClient client = new TheClient();
        client.FuncCall();
        Console.WriteLine("Out of Function");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more than what we said in the comments: the member function prevents its instance from being deleted even if it doesn't access to its members...  I tested and it is what I observed. Even with a real independant processing in the FuncLastLot (instead of the sleep that could add things...) . So the truth: the GC is good.  :-)

Comment: @iksess it sure is ^^

Comment: Your test doesn't actually invoke the GC, so I don't think it shows anything useful.

Comment: Yes, looking closer,  I think I'm still in the dark. The function Main ends soon, and the TheClient instance is deleted rapidely (I add a log in its destructor).  But the thread is existing although we lost the reference on it. I think the Thread class is special: it keeps a means to stay undeleted (a reference on itself, probably). And it keeps a reference on the running object. That's why running a function in another thread would prevent the function object to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Canton7 explanations in comments:

As a function makes access to instance members, it prevents the garbage collection. 
(Of course, having references on members implies keeping a reference on the instance. The 'this' is implicit in the code, but it is there... )